# list out owned file/directories and change its permissions

Tags: permissions, aix, chmod

Can anyone please tell how can I change files/directories owned by me only.

below is the command that list out files/directories owned by me

```
 find . -user <username>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your find already supports `-exec {} +`:

```
find . -user "$username" -exec chmod ... {} +
```

If it at least supports `-print0` and your `xargs` supports `-0`:

```
find . -user "$username" -print0 | xargs -0 chmod ...
```

Or if there are no newlines in the file paths:

```
find . -user "$username" | xargs -d '\n' chmod ...
```

Comment: `-exec ... {} +` is standard and POSIX, the other ones are not. `-0` is GNU and supported by a few others (like most recent BSDs, not AIX), `-d` is GNU only. All `find` implementations support `-exec ... {} ';'`